# How can I calculate Full Year in MDX in SSAS

Tags: ssas, mdx

I am using Built in time intelligence feature and I would like to calculate measures for the Full Year.
Eg if current member of date is at 2015/03/01; I want to have a calculated measure from 2015/01/01 till 2015/12/31.

```
CREATE MEMBER CurrentCube.[DimTime].[FY-FQ-FM DimTime Calculations].[Full Year] AS "NA" ; 
( 
  [DimTime].[FY-FQ-FM DimTime Calculations].[Year to Date]
, [DimTime].[Fiscal Year].[Fiscal Year].Members
, [DimTime].[Date].Members
, { [Measures].[Forecasts], [Measures].[Budget] } 
) 
= Aggregate( 
   { [DimTime].[FY-FQ-FM DimTime Calculations].[Current DimTime] } 
     * PeriodsToDate( 
         [DimTime].[FY-FQ-FM].[Fiscal Year]
       , [DimTime].[FY-FQ-FM].CurrentMember
       ) 
   ) ;
```

Comment: What does your date / time dimension structure look like? Do you have a user hierarchy within the dimension that is multi-leveled?

Comment: do you want to add this calculation into the `cube script` or are you just trying to include it in an ad hoc mdx script?

Comment: Thank your for you attention  . My date dimension is regular SSAS time dimension including fiscal period hierarchy just like normal quarter calendar hierarchy. I would like Full Year calculation part of the cube calculation; for example like below: @whytheq

Comment: Create Member 
  CurrentCube.[DimTime].[FY-FQ-FM DimTime Calculations].[Full Year] 
  As "NA" ;  
  (
    [DimTime].[FY-FQ-FM DimTime Calculations].[Year to Date],
    [DimTime].[Fiscal Year].[Fiscal Year].Members,
 [DimTime].[Date].Members,
    {
      [Measures].[Forecasts],
      [Measures].[Budget]
    }
  ) 
  =
  Aggregate(
             { [DimTime].[FY-FQ-FM DimTime Calculations].[Current DimTime] } 
             *
             PeriodsToDate(
                            [DimTime].[FY-FQ-FM].[Fiscal Year],
                            [DimTime].[FY-FQ-FM].CurrentMember
             )
  ) ;

Comment: thanks - I added it to your post and formatted into a readable format - fingers crossed you get a response. My knowledge of mdx is with standalone queries - I am not involved with the `cube scripts` so unable to help with this one. I get the feeling what you actually want is a YTD calculation?

Comment: @thebeginner, the above mentioned calculation is neither in a proper syntax of a `cube calculation` nor an `ad hoc MDX query`, could you please review it and put it in proper syntax? Please also explain what do you expect as the end result by using the Measures `Forecasts` and `Budget`. Do you expect an aggregated value starting from first day of current year to current date?

Comment: Thank you folks. I am not looking for YTD, but Full Year. YTD will aggregate the results starting from first date of current calendar till the current member date. If the user is at April 15, YTD will aggregate from 01jan15 till 31Apr15. 

I want aggregation of full year, ie 01jan15 till 31dec15.

Comment: Hi @AkshayRane. The code is from the built-in time intelligence calculation fields SSAS created automatically; it's valid one. Consider forecast and budget regular fields coming from a fact table.

Comment: @thebeginner, alright. Then I am not familiar with this type of code, haven't done it so far. But I am sure I can help with the logic part of it, you may use YTD on last date of year, for which you can first go back to the year using `Ancestors` function and then find out the last date in that year using `Descendants` and `Tail` functions as:
`Tail( DESCENDANTS( Ancestors( [Date].[Calendar].[Date].&[20050119], [Date].[Calendar].[Calendar Year]), [Date].[Calendar].[Date]) )`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @whytheq and @AkshayRane for the help.
I was able to do the full year using below.

```
(
    [DimTime].[FY-FQ-FM DimTime Calculations].[Full Year],
    [DimTime].[Fiscal Year].[Fiscal Year].Members,
    [DimTime].[Date].Members,
    {
      [Measures].[Forecasts],
      [Measures].[Budget]
    }

)


=

  Aggregate(
             { [DimTime].[FY-FQ-FM DimTime Calculations].[Current DimTime] } 
             *

            PeriodsToDate(
                            [DimTime].[FY-FQ-FM].[Fiscal Year],
                           (
                            ANCESTOR(  
                                      [DimTime].[FY-FQ-FM].CURRENTMEMBER,
                                      [DimTime].[FY-FQ-FM].[Fiscal Year] 
                                    )
                           )
                        )
          )
```